# inherited I for loop

Tags: c++, directx

been looking around some C++ and noticed this in a few classes, intellisense obviously threw up an error for it but this code had previously worked. Not asking for a fix just asking how it would have worked.

```
for(int i = 0; i < PACKAGE_MAX; i++)
    m_Package.push_back(&m_PrePackage[i]);

for(i = 0; i < PACKAGEPAIR_MAX; i++)
    m_PackagePair.push_back(&m_PrePackagePair[i]);
```

without them being nested the next statement carries over the declared i. And this continues for a few for loops. Is this an old .net method?

Surely after a few loops even though it wants to start when i = 0 it would end up jumping from 0 to 6 on the final for loop statement, same for the 2nd being in increments of 2. Might have been designed like that but this is just me reading around some old sources.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, but those loops don't have braces around the body, so the body is only one line (the indented one). In other words, the program first runs the first loop completely, then sets `i` to zero and runs the second loop completely and so on.

Comment: The variable `i` is probably declared somewhere within the same scope as both of those loops. The fact that the first loop redeclares `i` within its own scope is bad practice, but legal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question either. But if you wonder why one can reuse in the second loop the variable declared in the first, there's a [Visual Studio extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx) to do that, but the C++ standard states it shouldn't compile.

Comment: Thats probably it, thanks Dwarf.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that Microsoft's compiler allowed variables in the for loop's initializer to stay in scope past the for loop.

Here's a link to a compiler flag describing the behaviour: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx